# Color Ramp of Raster Rendering in MapServer

Tags: raster, mapserver

Does this proposed new syntax work yet? http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-6.html#proposed-new-syntax

Currently, I am still using this method for rendering the raster in Mapfile.

```
STYLE
   COLORRANGE 0 0 0  255 255 0 # black to yellow
   DATARANGE 0.0 100.0
   RANGEITEM "foobar"
END
```

However it doesn't work so well since it is linear interpolation and equal interval. In reality, the histogram of raster shows that data doesn't distribute with equal interval. In ArcGIS, the default method for classified raster rendering is Natural Breaks (Jenks).

Is there any new improvement for that in MapServer? Thanks